# invalid directory Users/node_modules/crypto-browserify react native

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native

I am trying to use a package I found on github (crypto-browserify) in my react native project, and used `npm install --save crypto-browserify` and then am importing it with `var crypto = require('crypto-browserify');`.  I can't seem to get this to work, I keep getting the above error, although crypto-browserify is in my node modules folder of my project.  Any help is much appreciated, I've been trying to solve this for hours!

Comment: Have you tried restarting your packager & cleaning the X Code project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had many issues trying to get crypto to work. Finally got it working using this package: `crypto-js`. Then in my file (this is how I encode to AES256):

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(rawStr, secret).toString()
```

Comment: this worked, looks like I'm better off using CryptoJs, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From there example looks like you want var crypto = require('crypto').